# Eclipse is deploying java files instead of class files

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish, eclipse-juno

Please excuse me if I do not use the proper terms. I am using eclipse Juno and Glassfish 3.1.2 internal plugin. I have several projects in my workspace with the source files in       `src/main/java` and the class files going to       `bin/main`. I did a Clean all projects and there are no compilation errors.
One project has 3 sub projects. I have the sub projects listed  in the main project's Deployment Assembly. However, when deploy it, I get an      `FileNotFoundException`.
When I look in the     `MainProject/WEB-INF/lib/subproject.jar/`     I only see `.java`    files. I compared this project to others and I cannot see any difference.

Answer (score 1):

A colleague figured out the solution. This is resolved by going into the deployment assembly and removing and adding the issue project back in.